# Can't fetch data object entirely in react, most likely due to of fetch call delay

Tags: reactjs, react-native, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to get Wordpress Rest API data about author.

So I'm using ComponentDidMount() with state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {},
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    apiFetch( { path: '/wp/v2/users/1' } )
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }));
}
```

in my render:

```
const { data } = this.state;
```

my data will be similar to this:

```
{
    id: "2",
    name: "Alex",
    image_url: {
        24: "http//...",
        48: "http//...",
        96: "http//..."
    }
}
```

So in my return if I do this:

```
<div className={className}>
    {data.name}
</div>
```

it is working and I will get "Alexander", but if add image url:

```
<div className={className}>
    {data.name}
    <img src={data.image_url['24']} />
</div>
```

I will get an error `Cannot read property '24' of undefined`.
As I understand there is some delay for fetching and that's why I get an error.

How can I add expectation of handling?
Sorry but in React I'm a beginner.

P.S. This is actually Gutenberg editor which is actually react, but has some core like `apiFetch` function, it is similar to fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said the reactive variable won't come until the response is resolved you just have to check if it exists like that

```js
<div className={className}>
    {data.name}
    { data.image_url ? (<img src={data.image_url['24']} />) : (<></>) }
</div>
```

Comment: omg, now it's working! I spent two days for it. Thanks a lot!